# How do I keep a zombie from despawning, since nametags apparently aren't working for me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making an adventure map in Minecraft, and I want to keep zombies from despawning. I've already tried nametags, and they *still* despawn.

Comment: Is there anything else you have tried before?  Along with that, what version of Minecraft are you running?

Comment: I'm running Minecraft 1.8 Forge

Comment: Did you make sure they cannot move? They could walk around and kill themselves.

Comment: They've been trapped, so there's no way they could die.

Comment: What do you mean "despawn"? If they get killed, it could possibly because they burned in the sun. You can give it headgear (pumpkin, helmet) or create a ceiling to cover the sun.

Answer (score 4):

If, for whatever reason, nametags don't keep a Zombie from **naturally despawning**, you can use some NBT magic to do the trick. Each and every *Living Entity* (aka Mob) has the NBT tag **PersistenceRequired** of the type *boolean*. This tag does exactly what you want to achieve.

The MinecraftWiki states the following:

> PersistenceRequired: 1 or 0 (true/false) - true if the mob must not despawn naturally.

Source:  https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format

Applying that tag to a Zombie can be done in two ways:

**1. Summon a new Zombie**
`/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {PersistenceRequired:true}`
Of course, you can edit the co-ordinates to whatever fits your needs. The tildes (~) are **relative** co-ordinates, thus representing the position of the executing player or command block.

**2. Edit the entity data of an existing Zombie**
`/entitydata @e[type=Zombie,r=3,c=1] {PersistenceRequired:true}`
For this command to work, the Zombie must be within three blocks in a spherical radius of who- or whatever executes the command (`r=3`). Of course, you can easily edit that parameter. This command also selects only the nearest Zombie to you or the respective command block (`c=1`). You can omit the count (c) parameter if you want to do this for **every** Zombie within the given radius.